# Get configuration while wiring dependency injection in Function App

Tags: azure, azure-functions, configuration-files, .net-core-2.1

We used this blog post https://blog.mexia.com.au/dependency-injections-on-azure-functions-v2 to set up dependencies in our Function App project.

DI part works fine, however, some classes require configuration settings.
In DiModule we have the following code:

```
  var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(Environment.CurrentDirectory)
                .AddJsonFile("serilog.json")
                .Build();
```

Environment.CurrentDirectory works on local machine, but doesn't work in Azure. I know that working implementation is

```
.SetBasePath(context.FunctionAppDirectory)
```

where context is of type ExecutionContext.
Is there a way to get ExecutionContext except from function parameter?

Or is there better way to load config in Function App (without loading it from every function call)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We end up using 2 kinds of settings with Azure Functions:
1. App settings 
2. Custom settings stored in the database with a cache layer

Serilog settings are stored in app settings.